# Angular component test error: TypeError Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I have a simple unit test that is done using karma/jasmine on an Angular 6 component.  From the pluralsight course and documentation I have gathered it appears I am mocking my service correctly that my component requires, but when the method is called to return data from the mock service I get the error saying property subscribe is undefined.

My "it" function is empty because the test fails once the component is constructed in the beforeEach method.  The constructor of the component is what calls the method I am attempting to test. Please see my code below.

```js
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

describe('Should construct MainComponent', () => {
 let mainComponent: MainComponent;
 let EMPLOYEES;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainComponent>;
 let mockDataService;

 beforeEach(() => {
  EMPLOYEES = [
   {
    "PrismEmployeeID": 1,
    "FirstName": "install2",
    "LastName": "account",
    "Initials": "IA ",
    "NickName": "",
    "SSN": "",
    "DateOfBirth": "09/26/2014",
    "HireDate": "09/26/2014",
    "OfficePhone": "9043943239",
    "OfficeFax": "9042246400",
    "ClassificationID": 133,
    "ClassificationDescription": "Claims Support U.S. Insurance",
    "SupervisorID": 32,
    "DepartmentID": 2,
    "DepartmentDescription": "Information Technology",
    "SupervisorName": "Jerry Sutton",
    "CountryID": 1,
    "CountryName": "United States"
   }
  ];

  mockDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['GetEmployees']);

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [MainComponent],
   providers: [{ provide: DataService, useValue: mockDataService }],
   schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
  });

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  mockDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['GetEmployees']);
 });

 it('should get an array Employees',
  () => {});
});
```

MainComponent

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { TableComponent } from './table/table.component';

@Component({
 selector: 'main',
 templateUrl: './main.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent {
 columns: string[] = ['PrismEmployeeID', 'LastName', 'FirstName', 'Initials', 'LastFour', 'BirthDate', 'HireDate', 'OfficePhone', 'OfficeFax', 'ClassificationDescription', 'SupervisorName', 'DepartmentDescription', 'CountryName'];
 loading: boolean = false;
 @Input() tableData: Employee[];

 constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
  this.loadEmployees();
 }

 loadEmployees() {
  this.loading = true;
  this._dataService.GetEmployees().subscribe((data) => {
   this.loading = false;
   this.tableData = data.json() as Employee[];
  });
 }

 onLoading(loading: boolean) {
  this.loading = loading;
 }

 onReloadData(reloadData: boolean) {
  this.loadEmployees();
 }
}

interface Employee {
 PrismEmployeeID: number;
 FirstName: string;
 LastName: string;
 Initials: string;
 NickName: string;
 SSN: string;
 DateOfBirth: string;
 HireDate: string;
 OfficePhone: string;
 OfficeFax: string;
 ClassificationID: number;
 ClassificationDescription: string;
 SupervisorID: number;
 DepartmentID: number;
 DepartmentDescription: string;
 SupervisorName: string;
 CountryID: number;
 CountryName: string;

 _selected: boolean;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<h2>Prism Employees</h2>
<div *ngIf="loading" class="d-flex justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
 <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"></div>
 <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
  <mat-spinner id="overlay"></mat-spinner>
 </div>
 <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"></div>
</div>

<div *ngIf='tableData'>
  <table-component #table (loading)="onLoading($event)" (reloadData)="onReloadData($event)" [data]="tableData" [displayedColumns]="columns"></table-component>
</div>
```

Comment: thats because you have not configured your spy object to return a value when `GetEmployees` is invoked. You need to return something

Comment: How do you configure a spy object to return a value?

Comment: I tried spyOn(mockDataService, 'GetEmployees').and.returnValue(EMPLOYEES); and now get error GetEmployees has already been spied upon

Comment: I leaved an answer

Comment: thanks trying it out now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that you are currently providing a stub of your service with no configured return for the `GetEmployees` method. Meaning that once the component invokes the previous function and subscribe to its (undefined) return, it will trigger an exception.

To solve this, you need to *fake* the return of that method. Based on [this answer](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1306#issuecomment-292681583) you can try this as follows:

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
...
mockDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj(DataService.Name, {'GetEmployees': of(EMPLOYEES)});
...
```

**UPDATE:**

In order for this to work though, you will have to refactor your `DataService.GetEmployees` method to have the following signature:

```
GetEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]>;
```

The current implementation of `DataService.GetEmployees` is a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction), as it returns the raw `Response` object from the old `Http` API, forcing the consumer (in this case the component) to know details about the underlying implementation (this detail being the use of `data.json() as Employee[]`)

Comment: I changed the service with your recommended changes and used the new HttpClient api and the error was resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot after some hours of googling found correct workout!

Answer (score 0):

```
spyOn(mockYourService, 'getSomeData').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} })
```

You could...
Return an actual observable in the spy

spyOn(mockYourService, 'getSomeData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(someData))
Maybe this will be preferred over the loop subscribe method, because if the call on the service is changing something in the component, this is something you probably will want to test